# Massive allocations with with CFString while writing to NSOutputStream in iOS

Tags: ios, sockets, memory-management, nsstring

I have problem with large number of allocations while writing to NSOutputStream. I am using few classes together that are supposed to stream data from AudioUnit to remote server. Code below:

AudioProcessor.m

```
Data *data = [Data sharedData]; //it's shared data I use to store information for the final socket

intFromBuffer = audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mData;
NSUInteger length = audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize;

NSMutableData *dataOut = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
[dataOut appendBytes:(const void *)intFromBuffer length:length * sizeof(SInt16)];

[data setOutput:dataOut]; //it writes data to the shared data
```

Data.m

```
@implementation Data
NSMutableData *output;
NSMutableData *input;

@synthesize output;
@synthesize input;

+(id)sharedData {
static Data *sharedData = nil;

@synchronized(self) {
    if (sharedData == nil) {
        sharedData = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedData;
  }
}

-(void) setOutput:(NSMutableData*)outputt{
    output = outputt;
}

-(void) setInput:(NSMutableData*)inputt{
    input = inputt;
}

@end
```

NetworkCommunication.m

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context {
//NSLog(@"changed!!!!");
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"output"]) {
    Data *data = [Data sharedData];
    [self writeOut:data.output];

    }
}

- (void)writeOut:(NSString *)s {
    NSString *dataTo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", s];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[dataTo dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
}
```

It generally creates great amount of data, which in 2,5 min was about 200 MB in virtual memory. I tried to simply pass `stringWithFormat:` directly to my `writeOut:` function however it gives nothing, not idea how to deal with it.

If someone asks why I use stringWithFormat, simply because I need to put `\n` for server to read the message.

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT 1:

I tied it different way. In my AudioProcessor.m (because that's the data is created - in the recorder callback) I set it this way:

```
dataOut = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
[dataOut appendBytes:(const void *)intFromBuffer length:length * sizeof(SInt16)];

net = [NetworkCommunication init];

const char *s = [dataOut bytes];

[[net outputStream] write:s maxLength:strlen(s)];
```

Now it generates insane allocations of type Malloc 1,00KB, and Malloc 2,00 KB with `NSThread callStackSymbol` and `NSThread callStackReturnAddresses`. What's still wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try sending C strings?

```
const char *s = [dataTo UTF8String];
[outputStream write:s maxLength:strlen(s)];
```